# Array to String conversion while login

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.1

I've tried to update my site from SF 3.0 to SF 3.1. Since then, this is impossible to login correctly.

> "Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DataCollector/RequestDataCollector.php
>   at line 377"

I checked that file, and it appears that $controller is an array instead of a string. There is the dump of the array :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Vehixel\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController' (length=48)
  1 => string 'login_checkAction' (length=17)
```

I have no idea of what could cause the issue. The login function was fully working before.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to #symfony IRC channel, especially to "bloodline". It seems to be a regression. We corrected it by adding the loginCheckAction & the logoutAction in the controller, even empty.